# Very simple Windows 7 user privileges

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts

How can one set the permissions of a particular folder such that a particular user can see it but is not able to open it (see its contents)?

My problem is that I can't select both checkboxes at the same time:

- "Read" under "Allow"
- "Show folder contents" under "Deny"

Next, whatever combination of "Allow" and "Deny" privileges seems to give me what I need neither at the basic "Security" options nor under "Advanced".

---

Addendum:

It seems that there is no problem doing this if the folder is not shared over the LAN.

As soon as it is shared the above won't work any more.

Any suggestions? I am really helpless ...

Comment: This seems like a strange way to do things. Why bother showing the folder if you want all of the content hidden anyway?

Comment: Is this awkward? I think it is legit to know that a particular folder exists even though I don't have the permission to look inside (yet)?

Comment: Perhaps you have a good reason. However, knowing a folder exists, but not being able to look at the contents doesn't jump out as useful to me.

Comment: ... but what is then the option "show folder contents" for ?

Comment: @lastprime - The permissions are described on Microsoft's website.  Showing the file contents wouldn't allow anyone to open the file but they would know the file exists

Answer (score 1):

```
Select folder > Right Click > Properties >Security >Edit
```

add a user with customized privileges ( `full control, modify, read and execute` etc. using allow / deny check boxes).

Comment: If it would be that simple! I am trying now since three days!

Comment: the first problem is that I can't select both the checkbox "Read" under "Allow" and the checkbox "List folder content" under "deny"

Comment: sorry dear i didn't this before but now i did, you are correct.

Comment: see from the option **Advanced** may be you can do something from here.

Comment: hm .. I think I tried all possible permutations of all the available checkboxes under "Advanced" ... maybe I am still missing the right one?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Access-based Enumeration.

I have seen people use **ABE**(Access-based Enumeration) for a similar scenario such as yours.
If you give them **List** permission, then if you are using ABE then it requires the user to have **READ** permissions and since **List** is lower than **Read** the files do not get displayed but the user should be able to still see the folder.

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd772681(v=ws.10).aspx